# Не корректно работает Skinning. OpenGL & ASSIMP

Tags: c#, opengl

Пытаюсь повторить уроки по OpenGL на C++, но использую OpenGL и C#, для загрузки модели использую AssimpNet 4.1.0.

Шейдер GLSL:

```
mat4 view =  viewRotation  * viewTranslation;
mat4 viewProjection = projection * view;

vec4 transformedPosition     = (boneTransform[boneID.x] * vec4(position, 1)) * boneWeight.x;
transformedPosition     += (boneTransform[boneID.y] * vec4(position, 1)) * boneWeight.y;
transformedPosition     += (boneTransform[boneID.z] * vec4(position, 1)) * boneWeight.z;
transformedPosition     += (boneTransform[boneID.w] * vec4(position, 1)) * boneWeight.w;
        
gl_Position   = viewProjection * transformedPosition;
```

Код C#:

```
List<Matrix4x4> transforms = new List<Matrix4x4>();

for (int i = 0; i < bones.Length; i++) {
    //TRS это комбинированная матрица, = node.Parent.Transform * node.Transform 
    //TRS и offset получаю из Assimp
    transforms.Add(TRS * offset);
}
GL.UniformMatrix4fv(material.boneTransformLocation, transforms.Count, false, transforms.ToArray());
```

Результат (слева как должно быть, справа что у меня):

Почему-то у меня робот получился немного вытянутым вверх и сплющенным по бокам, но это другая проблема, в целом кости тут на своих местах.
[image: описание]

При масштабировании происходит смещение, масштаб по оси Y был 1.5 и смещение было на ту же величину.
[image: описание]
Вращается не вокруг своей кости, а смещается, будто вращается вокруг центра модели.
[image: описание]

В чём же искать проблему, неправильно работают матрицы или я делаю не в том порядке как нужно?
Update: главная проблема была найдена в импорте модели, я пытался изменить размер модели и делал это не правильно, это как-то портило кости, придётся мириться с масштабом x100 при импорте FBX модели.

Однако, тогда появилась другая проблема:

Моя система координат отличается от той, что используется в Assimp.
[image: описание]

Для решения я использовал *Matrix4x4.Decompose*, затем инвертировал X и Y в position и rotation, то есть в -x, y, -z, затем из них снова создал матрицу.

В итоге проблема была в масштабе и перевёрнутой системе координат.

Comment: Конечно, ещё модель получилась вертикально отражена, но это другое, надо разбираться в опциях импорта Assimp и *PostProcessSteps.MakeLeftHanded*. Главной задачей было добиться работы костей для скелетной анимации.

Comment: И да, наверное, было ошибкой использовать перевёрнутую систему координат, как в Unity, от неё пока только проблемы и нигде не могу найти нюансы работы с ней и OpenGL.